# Don't tell me you forgot!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> You! I see you walking there
>
> Nary a worry or a care
>
> Come, listen to me speak
>
> My mind is strong, though my body is weak.
>
> I've got a riddle for you to ponder
>
> Something to think about whilst you wander
>
> It's a classic Riley, a word split in three
>
> For a prefix, and infix, and a suffix, you see:
>
> ---
>
> To be frank, my prefix is quite often heard
>
> It doth hath a way of being easily slurred.
>
> My infix is simple, third in the line,
>
> At least, of that which numbers twenty nine.
>
> My suffix is certainly your biggest contender
>
> Conquer him and you shall be showered with splendour.
>
> My whole, well, she's a tricky thing, but don't you go fret.
>
> You'll probably survive it.... as long as you don't forget.
>
> So now you've got all that you need to try,
>
> So tell me, dear puzzler. What am I?

Comment: Just a great Rhyme. Kudos

Comment: Thanks, @DEEM, it means a lot. Rhyming's the only skill I've got!

Comment: And being modest about your puzzling skills!

Comment: Of course, but he would never say so ;)

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You are a:

> WORDSEARCH

*To be frank, my prefix is quite often heard*
*It doth hath a way of being easily slurred.*

> WORD... When someone is being frank, you 'have their word'. The spoken word can be heard. You can also 'slur your words'.

*My infix is simple, third in the line,*
*At least, of that which numbers twenty nine.*

> SE... The third letter of the 29-letter Danish alphabet, equivalent to 'C'.

*My suffix is certainly your biggest contender*
*Conquer him and you shall be showered with splendour.*

> ARCH... As in 'arch-enemy' or 'arch-nemesis' i.e. your biggest rival.

*My whole, well, she's a tricky thing, but don't you go fret.*
*You'll probably survive it.... as long as you don't forget.*

> A WORDSEARCH is a puzzle (so can be tricky). Someone who is 'searching for the right word' is struggling to remember the um... the er... the... what was I going to say now??! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are

> History

Poem for Prefix

> To be frank, my prefix is quite often heard
>   It doth hath a way of being easily slurred.

Interpretation

> the letter "h" is a common letter in english, as in ***h**eard* itself
>  dot**h** and hat**h** show how the letter h is often pronounced different, like *th*
>
>  **So we have "h" as prefix.**

Poem for Infix

> My infix is simple, third in the line,
>   At least, of that which numbers twenty nine.

Interpretation

> *third in the line* refers to the word *is* (*My infix **is***...)
>  *which numbers twenty nine* refers to the number of letters of that line: 29
>
>  **So we have "is" as infix.**

Poem for suffix

> My suffix is certainly your biggest contender
>   Conquer him and you shall be showered with splendour.

Interpretation

> This story is really challenging.
>  But if I solve it, I hopefully get some applause from you :-)
>
>  **So we have "story" as suffix.**

Poem for whole

> My whole, well, she's a tricky thing, but don't you go fret.
>   You'll probably survive it.... as long as you don't forget.

Interpretation

> Its always good not to forget history to not make the same mistakes again and again.

Answer (score 1):

You are a

> SCHOOL

```
To be frank, my prefix is quite often heard    
It doth hath a way of being easily slurred.
```

> "S" is quite often heard. Cubemaster may be actually slurring his words (doth - does, hath - has). Plus, "It doth hath a way of being eathily thlurred" is fun to say.

```
My infix is simple, third in the line,
At least, of that which numbers twenty nine.
```

> "C" is the third letter in the Swedish alphabet of 29 characters.

```
My suffix is certainly your biggest contender
Conquer him and you shall be showered with splendour.
```

> "COOL" (CHOOL) Being cool in school was something I had to contend with. That was until i stopped caring about being noticed. Then I became cool and was "showered with splendo(u)r (sp?)".

```
You'll probably survive it.... as long as you don't forget.
```

> You'll probably survive School, unless you forget your homework. The phrase "Don't tell me you forgot!" was yelled by my teacher many a times.